# How to synchronise output in Julia language?

Tags: julia, jupyter

I'm trying to loop in a cycle, output each value and then print the result of some other function.

But the output looks strange, the output of the loop mixed with the output of the other function.

Is there any way to synchronise it? I'm using Jupyter, not Julia console.

[image]

Comment: this has already been fixed [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/pull/392), but  unreleased yet. you should work on the master via `Pkg.checkout("IJulia")`

Comment: @GnimucK. thank you!

Comment: It might be worth marking this question as solved even though the answer was provided by a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gnimuc K. pointed out in comments:

> this has already been fixed here, but unreleased yet. you should work
>   on the master via Pkg.checkout("IJulia")